# how to extract these strings in Python using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string below:

```
stra = "hello (70/2009). Target no. 39/K/20/MEM/2019 world no. 12/2020 good 21/PMK.011/2010 test"
```

I want to extract the following substrings which contains "/" sign:

1. 70/2009
2. 39/K/20/MEM/2019
3. 12/2020
4. 21/PMK.011/2010

Can anyone advise me on how to do it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: something like `\S+/\S+` should work

Comment: How about  \d+\/\d+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using regex:

```
import re

text = "hello (70/2009). Target no. 39/K/20/MEM/2019 world no. 12/2020 good 
21/PMK.011/2010 test"
data = re.findall("\d+\S+\d+", text)
print(data)

>>>> ['70/2009', '39/K/20/MEM/2019', '12/2020', '21/PMK.011/2010']
```

Answer (score 1):

Not regex, but you can split then find '/' in substring like this.

```
stra = "hello (70/2009). Target no. 39/K/20/MEM/2019 world no. 12/2020 good 21/PMK.011/2010 test"
l = [x for x in stra.split() if '/' in x]
print(l)
```